# Regarding Wifi P2P in Android Programming

Tags: android, wifi, wifip2p

I am new to android programming. I had some doubts regarding Wifi peer to peer connections. 
1. Does it require either of the devices to be connected to the internet?
2. For detecting peers nearby, the device has to know that the other device has wifi p2p service turned on. So do we have to tell the listening device that the p2p service is turned on? Or is it done automatically? Basically what i want to know is, when wifi p2p service is turned on in both the devices and one of the device is discovering for peers nearby, will the device which is discovering find the peer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#api

Hello please see above...

To answer your question, the peer discovery process will only discover peers which have wifi turned on obviously. Note that wifi-P2P is not something you can turn on! you just need wifi to be on as described in setting the process up in the webpage above.

You will need to include different handlers for when if the connection is lost etc. If you have a look at the website above and look at the google sample of the wifi-peer-to-peer you should have no issue understanding this!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have understood the point. Can you just confirm about it?
Lets say i've written an application and whenever it is launched it calls the intialize() method for wifi p2p. So this application is currently running on two devices which are in range. And i called discover peers method on one device. So does it detect the other device? Thanks.
And one more thing, you said turning on wifi turns on wifi p2p right? Then why do we need to check the WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION status? Cant we just check the wifi state?

Comment: For your first question, yes it does. As long as both of the device Wi-Fi is on then it will detect it however as you will realize connecting/authenticating will involve many other steps needed.

As for the WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION this is to detect if either has cancelled or lost connection or whatever. Yes this is different to the WIFI listener however it is part of the same thing technically. As WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION is a intent of the manger which you setup at the start which requires Wifi to be on... Hope this helps.

Comment: I had one more question. My application is currently turned on in only one device and it calls the initialize and discover methods, the other device has only its wifi turned on. So will the discovering device detect the other device?

Comment: In technical terms it should however it probably would not... If you look at the google link i gave you, there is a service bound you an setup to detect incoming requests/ connections that will make it feed back a note to the person trying to discover that a device is "ready to connect"

Comment: Okkay got it. That helped.

Comment: Please open new threads for these and tag me in... if you do some research you will find the answer! try to be more independent